# Minor tooltip bug on /review page for votes display

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, tooltips

In the `/review` page, for all posts, as shown in snapshot below, it shows a tooltip saying "total no. of votes for 0 answers". However I think **it should show 1 answers instead of 0**.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good catch, this will be fixed in the next build (later today/tonight).